# Rotate an object right or left 90 degrees and move forward on a grid

Tags: java, point

I have the following scenario for which i need to create a java program. Any ideas how to implement this:

A small robot which can move on a grid, controlled by simple commands.
In this example, it will move on a 5x5 grid with a simple co-ordinate system - 0,0 is the bottom left, 4,4 is the top right.

We can control the robot by sending it a string consisting of commands, such as the following: RFLFFRF

R means rotate right 90 degrees, L rotate left 90 degrees, and F means move forward one square in the direction the Rover is currently facing. The Rover starts at 0,0 facing North ("up" the grid).
I need to write a program which will accept strings of commands and return the grid position of the obot after those commands

Answer (score 0):

Write a robot class containing a position and an orientation, then implement the three commands (R, L and F) on it. Finally, write code to parse the command sequence and run the commands. Create a new robot, run the command sequence on it and output the position when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Function:
     public int Robot(int input1,int input2,String input3,String input4)
     {
        int flag=0;
        String s[]=input3.spilt("-");
        int x=Integer.parseInt(s[0]);
        int y=Integer.parseInt(s[1]);
        String curface=s[2];
         for(int i=0;i0){x--;}else{flag=1;break;}break;
                    case "E":if(x0){y--;}else{flag=1;break;};
                }
          }
        }
        String out="";
        if(flag==0)
        {
            out=""+x+"-"+y+"-"+curface;
        }
        else
        {
           out=""+x+"-"+y+"-"+curface+"-ER";
        =
        }
        return out;
    }